# Using same wildcarded type in multiple classes

Tags: java, generics

I want to do something like this:

```
public class Tree<A extends Ability>{
   ...
}
```

In the tree I want to use Objects that inherit from Ability. The tree consists of nodes, that have as a payload an Ability:

```
public class Node<A extends Ability>{
    public A getAbility(){ ... }
    ...
}
```

If I try to use A in a method of the Tree, say search, I get an error:

```
public void read(){
    Node node = searchForTheNode(...);
    node.getAbility(); // <- this gives me an error
}
```

The error says, incompatible types: java.lang.Object and A. 
What am I missing, how can I use the same generic Type in Tree and in Node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Tree<> and Node<> classes are separate then the 'A's aren't necessarily the same thing. If you're writing Tree and Node. I would nest Node inside Tree:

```
class Tree<A extends Ability> {

    static class Node {
        A method() {
            A a = null;
            return a;
        }
    }
}
```

This way you constrain 'A' once and the 'A' that Node and Tree refer to are the same type.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. The error is: "Cannot access 'A' in 'package.Tree'"

Answer (score 0):

try this: `Node<A> node = searchForTheNode(...);`